# beelinereader patent coverage

Tags: patent-infringement, software, design-patent

I am a fan of beelinereader, I want to use same idea to implement a reader app,in their website it is written that their technology is patented as here https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150234788A1/en?oq=20150234788
Does using gradient in the text(possibly any other color combination that beelinereader doesnt show in their list),which also means using different color for each letter, violate their patent coverage ?
It sounds little weird the idea that typing letters in different colors violates a patent.

Comment: Please be advised that the linked document is an application, not a patent. Claims in applications are usually broader than the resulting patent (which may never be granted).

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the patent application was granted.  You may want to read the claims carefully to see if the claims that you were worried about were allowed by the examiner.

Your use of different colors for each letter and the claimed use of color gradients for each letter may only be an obvious use.

[US9026907B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9026907B2/en)

Comment: This could be a good answer with more content. Explain that to infringe you need to implement each and every aspect of a claim. You could try reading claim 1 and actually answer the question. Also your second paragraph seems to relate to patentability which isn't asked.

Comment: "obvious use" is not a patent infringement related concept.